# Detection if a pointer is pointing in the device or host in CUDA

Tags: cuda

In CUDA are there any way of knowing if the pointer is pointing in memory on the device or the host.

A made op example of this could be:

```
int *dev_c, *host_c;
cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_c, sizeof(int) );
host_c = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
```

I can of course look at the name, but are there any way of looking ad the pointer dev_c and host_c and saying, host_c points ad the host and dev_c points ad the device.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way you can tell if the pointer is allocated on the host or on the device.

Answer (score 9):

Starting (I think) CUDA 4 and Fermi GPUs. Nvidia supports [UVA (Unified Virtual Address Space)](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#unified-virtual-address-space).
Function [cudaPointerGetAttributes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__UNIFIED_1gab5cad40942fd554556035741d3fe5a2) seems to do exactly what you're asking for. Note that I believe it only works for host pointers allocated with cudaHostAlloc (and not c malloc).

Answer (score 6):

This is a small example showing how [Unified Virtual Addressing](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__UNIFIED.html#group__CUDART__UNIFIED) can be used to detect if a pointer is pointing to host or device memory space. As @PrzemyslawZych has pointed out, it works only for host pointers allocated with `cudaMallocHost`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<cuda.h>   
#include<cuda_runtime.h>

#include<assert.h>
#include<conio.h>

#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        getch();
        if (abort) { exit(code); getch(); }
    }
}

int main() {

    int* d_data;
    int* data; // = (int*)malloc(16*sizeof(int));
    cudaMallocHost((void **)&data,16*sizeof(int));

    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_data,16*sizeof(int)));

    cudaDeviceProp prop;
    gpuErrchk(cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop,0));

    printf("Unified Virtual Addressing %i\n",prop.unifiedAddressing);

    cudaPointerAttributes attributes;
    gpuErrchk(cudaPointerGetAttributes (&attributes,d_data));
    printf("Memory type for d_data %i\n",attributes.memoryType);
    gpuErrchk(cudaPointerGetAttributes (&attributes,data));
    printf("Memory type for data %i\n",attributes.memoryType);

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems that it is possible: the following example shows an `array` allocated with `new` using `cudaPointerGetAttributes` to determine that it does not reside on the GPU (by returning an error). https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward-1.0/blob/3909e8e6ee27a3da49056c5f71b863829e8c8ff4/studies/cuda_studies/src/study_1.cu#L51-L57

Answer (score 3):

Not directly. One approach would be to write an encapsulating class for device pointers so that is it absolutely clear that device and host pointers are different in your code. You can see a model of this idea in the [Thrust](http://thrust.github.com/) template library, which has a type called `device_ptr` to clearly delineate device and host pointer types.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's possible. Pointer points some address in memory and you don't now if this is host or device memory. When program starts it can be put  in (almost) every address in memory of OS so you can't trying guess. You should note variables names.