# Is there any way to determine whether a variable is on the device or in the host?

Tags: cuda, gpu

Consider the following example:

```
float *h_var= new float[n*sizeof(float)]; // host
//Assign data
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
   h_var[i] = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);;

float *d_var; //device
checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc( &d_var, n));
checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(d_var, h_var, n, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
```

Is there any way to determine whether a variable is on the device or in the host?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detection if a pointer is pointing in the device or host in CUDA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891610/detection-if-a-pointer-is-pointing-in-the-device-or-host-in-cuda).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the device, the only pointers you have access to are device pointers.

On the host, for pointers to dynamically allocated regions (such as your `h_var` and `d_var`), and if [Unified Virtual Addressing](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__UNIFIED.html#group__CUDART__UNIFIED) is enabled, you can determine whether the pointer points to device or host memory using the [cudaPointerGetAttributes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__UNIFIED.html#group__CUDART__UNIFIED_1gab5cad40942fd554556035741d3fe5a2) runtime API call.

Also, assuming you want to manage `n` `float` types, the size parameter you should be using is not `n` but `n*sizeof(float)`

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly clear on what you are asking but, if you declare a variable with `__device__` outside of the main function it will be used as a variable type qualifier and it puts that variable in global GPU memory.

What it looks like you have done is copy the contents of the variable h_var on the host to d_var on the device. If you want to copy the contents back after the GPU does some computation you can do the following:

```
cudaMemcpy(h_var, d_var, n, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

The variable d_var will still be on the device until you deallocate it using:

```
cudaFree(d_var);
```